# With socket.io, express, ejs, and node.js, how would I send and recieve a json file?

Tags: json, node.js, express, socket.io, ejs

Ok so this is what I want to do:

### What I know

1. Compile variables into an object

   ---

### What I don't know

2. How would I convert the object to a json, send the json to the server, then have the server send back another json file?

   ---

### What I know

3. Use JSON.parse and use the contents of the file.

Comment: To clarify: you want to pass a JS object between the client and server over socket.io? Can you share any code you've already tried? This is not a site to have people write code for you, only to solve specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and send a Javascript object with socket.io like this:

```
// create object
var obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "hello";
obj.prop2 = "goodbye";
obj.whatever = "something else";
obj.value = 492;

// send object to server
socket.emit("someMessage", obj);
```

Then, on the receiving end of things at your server, you'd have something like this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on("someMessage", function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);    // copy of object that the client sent
    });
});
```

If the data is initially in a file, then you have to somehow get that file into memory and parse it into JSON before using this procedure.  You are not very specific about what you're trying to do with a file.